# GetProcAddress undefined in minifilter programs

Tags: getprocaddress, minifilter

I 'm working on a minifilter project. How can I call GetProcAddress within a minifilter program? My compiler keeps telling me  "GetProcAddress undefined assume extern returning int". According to msdn, I might need to include window.h. But if I do so, many more other compiler errors occur? what should do?

Answer (score 0):

There is no kernel mode equivalent of `GetProcAddress`.

May be you need to check, why do you need that. If you want to load and call some function of your DLL, then probably instead of DLL link it statically with your driver.

Also, you can't load any DLL in kernel mode.

If you think you really want to do this, check following articles

[Calling a DLL in a Kernel-Mode Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463187.aspx)

[Writing Kernel Mode DLLs](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=171)

Answer (score 0):

`MmGetSystemRoutineAddress` can be used for the same purpose.

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-mmgetsystemroutineaddress